# If $A+B\ge C$, can we find positive operators $A_1\le A$ and $B_1\le B$ such that $A_1+B_1=C$?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive operators on a Hilbert space. $C$ is a positive operator with $A+B\ge C$. Can we find positive operators $A_1\le A$ and $B_1\le B$ such that $A_1+B_1=C$?

Comment: Nit picking: if $A+B=C$ then yes.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Of course in this case you are right. What about the general case for $C< A+B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true in general. Take for instance
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \ C=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $C\leq A+B$, and if $0\leq A_1\leq A$ then $A_1=t A$ for some $t\in[0,1]$. Similarly, $0\leq B_2\leq B$ implies $B=s B$ for some $s\in [0,1]$. It is not possible then to have $C=A_1+B_1=tA+sB$.

Comment: THX! Simple and elegant explanation.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not positive operators, they are non-negative operators.

Comment: That may sound reasonable, but it's not how the term is usually used. In any case, it is trivial to tweak the example and make all matrices invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Set $A,B,C>0$, observe the problem
$$ \lambda=\min\left\{\frac{x^tCx}{x^tAx} \colon x^tx=1\right\}.$$
If $\lambda >0$, define $$ A_1= \lambda A, A_2=C-A_1.$$